# Python plot shows numbers instead of Dates on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, date, plot

I'm trying to plot a stock chart.
My DataFrame structure looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 503 entries, 0 to 506
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Date      503 non-null object
Open      503 non-null float64
High      503 non-null float64
Low       503 non-null float64
Close     503 non-null float64
Volume    503 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 27.5+ KB
```

When I try to plot the data using the Close-column I get numbers on the x axis, but I want to plot it with the dates using 3 month ticks. How can I achieve that?

At the moment the code for the plot looks like this:

```
dax_data["Close"].plot(label = "Dax Close", figsize = (16,8), title = "Dax Prices")
plt.legend();
```

[Here you can see the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJz9J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "DataFrame.plot()' use by default the dataframe index as x values.
You should do like this :

```py
dax_data.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Close', label = "Dax Close", figsize = (16,8), title = "Dax Prices")
```

And to have 3 month ticks :

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

### Your code to get dax_data

ax = dax_data.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Close', label = "Dax Close", figsize = (16,8), title = "Dax Prices")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval = 3)) # to display ticks every 3 months
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m-%Y")) # to set how dates are displayed
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.